# Open Chrome PDF viewer dialogue with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to offer users the option to save the current webpage as a PDF using Chrome natively, no other browser support is required and introducing a 3rd party system is not a practical option.

Currently I have to manually instruct the user where the "Open PDF in Preview" link is within the print dialogue and only offer the following button:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); window.print();">
    PDF Preview
</a>
```

I would like to jump the user straight to the PDF preview dialogue for them to save, the following will of course not work, but is more similar to what I would like to achieve.

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); window.print('pdf');">
    PDF Preview
</a>
```

Comment: I think you will have to convert your page to PDF by using javascript. One of the libraries available is jsPDF. The library is great however documentation is the problem with it.

Comment: @whiterabbitj 3rd party isn't an option, I really only want to use Chrome's native system although I suspect that Chrome does not have the option to do what I've asked, hence the correct answer may just be "This can't be done".

Comment: congrats answered your own question! But the only way to achieve a downloadable PDF is trough using these libraries...

Comment: @whiterabbitj ha, maybe although I did so without any proof. The problem with the libraries is they're quite intensive to implement among the range of pages that I have available. It's not worth the time to invest vs just showing users how to download via the preview dialogue.

Comment: Yeah would be different instructions for every browser however. Will have to write those print style sheets as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It is not possible to do this.**

Chrome currently meets the HTML standard as "print" generically means obtaining the page in some physical way, be that a traditional printed document or a PDF. How it chooses to do this is up to the browser vendor.

Additionally Chrome users can select their default action for printing to be PDF or a printer on their network.

From that I would infer that it's unlikely Chrome would let the web application override the user preference.

**Sources**

- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#simple-dialogs
- https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#obtain-a-physical-form
- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/D0CYzpWx7xE;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/save%20as%20PDF

Comment: +1, the answer could have just been "No, you can't", but referencing the spec is informative to understand the context behind the browser's behavior.