# How to save an HTML page in a PDF whit a button?

Tags: html, pdf, web-applications

Hi guys i need to save my HTML page in a PDF file how i can do that ? 
Function or external app?

this is one example of my page:

|
v
[image]

Can anyone link me a tutorial? it's my first experience with these things

i need to store the pdf in a directory in the server .. whit window.print() user must click Print in the layout... i want a function that print in automatic without any user action

Comment: The browser normally has a 'save as PDF' option, is this suitable or do you need need any kind of customisation?

Comment: The following may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52094841/open-chrome-pdf-viewer-dialogue-with-javascript

Comment: Hy  @AlexanderDeSousa i need to store the pdf in a directory in the server .. whit window.print() user must click Print in the layout,,,  i want a function that print in automatic without any user action

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a button to save a page as PDF, you might just assign `window.print` to the button. All of the modern browsers will allow the user to save document as a PDF from the print dialogue.

EDIT: for storing PDF on a server you may use a library like [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)